# Getting current element value among multiple elements which has same class name with no id

Tags: jquery

How can i get current selected element value from multiple element which has same class but does not have id.

Where Same element is present in multiple sections in one page.

e.g.

```
<input type="button" style="width: 20px; margin-left: 50%"  class="objectbackColor" />
```

I have this element present in multiple sections in one page. 
how can i get current selected button value.

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/uoch2chk/1/)**

Comment: how do you select a button.. do you mean click

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uoch2chk/2/)

using jquery click method.

```
$('.objectbackColor').on('click',function(){
    alert($(this).val())
});
```

Answer (score 1):

### Please try using this

```
var selected_val;

$(".objectbackColor").on('click', function(){
 selected_val = $(this).val();
});
```